# Как мне сохранить правильные границы на треугольниках CSS при наведении курсора?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation, hover

Можно ли исправить зависание при ховере см. http://jsfiddle.net/2AXhR/, чтобы при наведении активировался правильный треугольник, а не иногда соседний?

Иногда активируется неправильный треугольник, потому что ограничивающая область каждого элемента треугольника на самом деле не треугольник, а прямоугольник, поэтому даже если курсор может казаться поверх одного треугольника, на самом деле он находится поверх другого, который перекрывается и имеет более высокий z-индекс.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
  .t {
     position:relative;
     top:55px;
     left:5px;
  }
  .t div {
     position:absolute;
     width: 0px;
     height: 0px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 0 100px 173.2px 100px;
     border-color: transparent transparent #0079c5 transparent;
     transition:all 1s;
     -webkit-transition:all 1s;
     -moz-transition:all 1s;
     cursor:pointer;
     transform-origin:200px 173px;
     -webkit-transform-origin:200px 173px;
     -moz-transform-origin:200px 173px;
     z-index:10;
  }
  .t div:hover {
      z-index:20;
      border-color: transparent transparent #009cff transparent;
  }
  .t div:nth-child(1) {
     transform:rotate(30deg);
     -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);
     -moz-transform:rotate(30deg);
  }
  .t div:nth-child(1):hover {
     transform:rotate(30deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
     -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
     -moz-transform:rotate(30deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
  }
  .t div:nth-child(2) {
     transform:rotate(90deg);
     -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
     -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
  }
  .t div:nth-child(2):hover {
     transform:rotate(90deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
     -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
     -moz-transform:rotate(90deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
  }
  .t div:nth-child(3) {
     transform:rotate(150deg);
     -webkit-transform:rotate(150deg);
     -moz-transform:rotate(150deg);
  }
  .t div:nth-child(3):hover {
     transform:rotate(150deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
     -webkit-transform:rotate(150deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
     -moz-transform:rotate(150deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
  }
  .t div:nth-child(4) {
     transform:rotate(210deg);
     -webkit-transform:rotate(210deg);
     -moz-transform:rotate(210deg);
  }
  .t div:nth-child(4):hover {
     transform:rotate(210deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
     -webkit-transform:rotate(210deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
     -moz-transform:rotate(210deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
  }
  .t div:nth-child(5) {
     transform:rotate(270deg);
     -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
     -moz-transform:rotate(270deg);
  }
  .t div:nth-child(5):hover {
     transform:rotate(270deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
     -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
     -moz-transform:rotate(270deg) translate(-15%, -10%);
  }
  .t div:nth-child(6) {
     transform:rotate(330deg);
     -webkit-transform:rotate(330deg);
     -moz-transform:rotate(330deg);
  }
```

```html
 <div class="t">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
  </div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How can I maintain proper boundaries on CSS triangles when hovering with cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23107646/7394871) от участника  [@Dane Iracleous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644337/dane-iracleous).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/23107646/7394871

Answer (score 4):

### Версия 2, чище, лучше (исправляет проблемы IE и FF)

*Исправленные проблемы:*

1. IE проигнорировал `overflow:hidden;` свойство, и события наведения были запущены за пределами видимых треугольников.
2. Почему-то в firefox на треугольниках появлялись линии.
3. курсор возвращается к значению по умолчанию, если он находится между треугольниками.

*Описание*

Этот подход использует `skewX()` для создания треугольников. Вам не нужен «border trick» для их создания, и вам также не нужно свойство переполнения. С помощью этой техники вообще нет **перекрывающихся элементов**, поэтому события наведения не могут запускать два элемента одновременно.

Второй div скрывает половину перекошенного элемента для создания треугольника и переводится вместе с ним при наведении курсора с помощью селектора + CSS.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### ```css
.t div{
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;

    transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;

    transition:all 1s;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s;
    -moz-transition:all 1s;
}

.t .wrap{
    top:50%; left:50%;

    -ms-transform: skewX(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(30deg);
    transform: skewX(30deg);
}

.t .wrap .triangle {
    position:relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 173px;
    background-color: #0079c5;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:1;
}
.t .wrap .mask{
    width:100%;
    height:115.5%;
    background-color: #fff;
    left:100%;
    z-index:2;

    -ms-transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(30deg);
    transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(30deg);
} 

.t .wrap .triangle:hover{
    background-color: #009cff;

    transform:  translate(10%, 10%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(10%, 10%);
    -moz-transform: translate(10%, 10%);
}

.t .triangle:hover + .mask{
    -ms-transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(30deg) translate(17.5%, 0);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(30deg) translate(17.5%, 0);
    transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(30deg) translate(17.5%, 0);
}

.t > div:nth-child(2){
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) skewX(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) skewX(30deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg) skewX(30deg);
}
.t > div:nth-child(3){
    -ms-transform: rotate(120deg) skewX(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) skewX(30deg);
    transform: rotate(120deg) skewX(30deg);
}

.t > div:nth-child(4){
    -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewX(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewX(30deg);
    transform: rotate(-60deg) skewX(30deg);
}
.t > div:nth-child(5){
    -ms-transform: rotate(-120deg) skewX(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-120deg) skewX(30deg);
    transform: rotate(-120deg) skewX(30deg);
}
.t > div:nth-child(6){
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg) skewX(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg) skewX(30deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg) skewX(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="t">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
        <div class="mask"></div>
    </div>
   <div class="wrap">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
        <div class="mask"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
        <div class="mask"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
        <div class="mask"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
        <div class="mask"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
        <div class="mask"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Версия 1 (оригинаал) : [фиддле для демо V1](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/bZxn9/)

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23188768/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>